# I need to execute Java script function from c# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iis

I  need to execute Java script  function from c# code behind . Using Asp.net server control Repeater and checking condition when condition is true need to run java script function which will turn hyper link display block this is my javascript function

```
function MyFunction(username) {
  document.getElementById("hyp").style.display = "block";
}
```

This  is my Asp.net code after that condition if true I call c# code behind method writeText() :

```
<%# Eval("part2").ToString() == "part2" ? writeText(Eval("Albumtitle").ToString(), Eval("Albumtitle").ToString(), inc.ToString()) : writeLink(Eval("Albumtitle").ToString(), Eval("Albumtitle").ToString())%>

protected string writeText(string PageDataId, string AlbumId, string a)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hwa", "MyFunction('Checkjj');", true);
    string html = "";
    html += "";
    return html;
}
```

This c# call javascript function which display html anchor to block which was display none at the start

Here is that anchor tag

```
<a id="hyp" name="hyp"  href="#" class="lightbox<%=inc+"b" %>">Part II</a>
```

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: @SivaRajini i get this error Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Answer (score 0):

With your html: `<a id="hyp" name="hyp"  ...` add the attribute `runat="server"`. Then on the server side you can access the object like if it were a server control.

There is not need to execute Javascript on the server side to perform the action you need.

Something like on "ItemDataBound" Event for the repeater:

```
  void MyRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
string someVar = "someValue"  ;  
           ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("hyp")).Attributes.Add ("css", "lightbox" + someVar);          
       }
```

In order to use this event don't forget to add the event and the runat server attribute :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MyRepeater_ItemDataBound">

       <a id="hyp" name="hyp"  href="#" runat="server">Part II</a>

</asp:Repeater>
```

You can find this blog helpful:

- http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/repeater-onitemdatabound-cs/
- http://www.nullskull.com/q/10259645/anchor-tag-not-well-formed-when-id-is-provided.aspx

Comment: if i add runat server in my tag then i cant use class="lightbox<%=inc+"b" %>"> it give me error

Comment: that is not correct... You could add it on itemDatabound event

Comment: how please guide me ?

Comment: I just added a quick sample

Comment: @JayZee You add `runat="server"` to the beginning of the attribute list, then put the class attribute at the end of the attributes list. Then run it. It should run.

Comment: @Dalorzo iuse it like that    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="MyRepeater_ItemDataBound">      it gave me error Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'interview.MyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: ItemDataBound event needs to be either public or protected. Like protected void MyRepeater_ItemDataBound

Comment: @Dalorzo ur code work but problem still same i need to write that class="lightbox<%=inc+"b" %>" because this with that inc variable my jquery open light box so it recognise that class so please give me solution where i can use class="lightbox<%=inc+"b" %>" :(

Comment: if its PHP i can do very easily but this dot net really a problem

Comment: @mason if i use runat="server" then cant use this class attribute  class="lightbox<%=inc+"b" %>" and if i use then it give me this error Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.